# Python performance time in minus

Tags: python, performance, datetime, time, performance-testing

I used to use the same method but I get the performance time in seconds (e.g., 0.0003). This time I do not know why I am getting the time in minus. I used to use the same device. I use Linux Ubuntu 18. This is an example:

```
import time 
import datetime

start = time.perf_counter() 
print("something")
duration = time.process_time() - start
print("performance time: ", duration, "sec.")
```

Output:

```
performance time:  -30559.147778458 sec.
```

Is there anything wrong? how to get perf. time in positive values?

Comment: You are subtracting an Orange from an Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.perf_counter()` and `time.process_time()` don't return the same data... You cannot subtract one from the other and expect anything but garbage.

[`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter)

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a **performance counter**, i.e. a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short duration. It does include time elapsed during sleep and is system-wide. **The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of consecutive calls is valid.**

[`time.process_time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time)

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of **the sum of the system and user CPU time of the current process**. It does not include time elapsed during sleep. It is process-wide by definition. **The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of consecutive calls is valid.**

---

Pick either `time.perf_counter()` or `time.process_time()` - but don't confuse the returned values.

I suspect you'll want to use `time.process_time()`.

Comment: Thanks. That's was a typo.